# how to install dlib in windows 10?

Tags: python

I have been trying to install dlib for a long time and never succeed. and I did follow below link to install cmake, visual studio then pip install cmake and pip install dlib. and I still got the same error below.  Could anyone help pls? Thanks

https://medium.com/analytics-vidhya/how-to-install-dlib-library-for-python-in-windows-10-57348ba1117f

```
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: 
'C:\Users\test\miniconda3\envs\opencv\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; 
sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\test\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-zcj3x2_4\\dlib_a07e701c04944b5ab19be9c6a4a8d5c0\\setup.py'"'"';
 __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\test\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-zcj3x2_4\\dlib_a07e701c04944b5ab19be9c6a4a8d5c0\\setup.py'"'"';
f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');
f.close();
exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\test\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-dbzq5p8_\install-record.txt' 
--single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers 
'C:\Users\test\miniconda3\envs\opencv\Include\dlib' 
Check the logs for full command output.
```